# How can i use a function inside the same script file without getting $args ending up quoted as i. e. "arg1 arg2"

Tags: maven, powershell, maven-3, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell (v2.0) function:

```
function mvn{
    param(
        [parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        $args
    )
    <# calling the realmaven.bat file here with the args #>
    "$env:M2_HOME\bin\mvn.bat" $args
}
```

Now I would like to use another function in this scripts file using the former:

```
function mvn-failsafe-debug {
    param (
        [string] $Dmaven_failsafe_debug="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,server=y,address=Maven,suspend=n",
        [parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        $args
    )
    <# 
       calling the predefined mvn function above
    #>
    mvn `-Dmaven.failsafe.debug=$Dmaven_failsafe_debug $args
}
```

The generated command when using as `mvn-failsafe-debug clean install` on the powershell prompt now is something like:

> realmaven.bat ... "clean install"

but I need it to be

> realmaven.bat ... clean install

How to achieve that?

Comment: In `mvn-failsafe-debug` shouldn't your Position for the remaining arguments be 1 and the debug string Position 0? Otherwise you won't be able to set it positionally, and any attempt to do so will end up in the remaining args.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the entire source of you woes but for starters don't name a variable `$args`. This is an automatic variable in PowerShell. You can look at [about_Automatic_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) to see what I mean.

If nothing else you should rename that line in `param`. I simply changed the variable name to `$remains`.

The in that same regard you could change the calling function to something like this.

```
function mvn{
    param(
        [parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        $remains
    )
    Write-Host $remains
    Start-Process "$($env:M2_HOME)\bin\mvn.bat" -ArgumentList ($remains -join "")
}
```

Comment: I renamed the `$args` as you suggested, but the test still fails - it really should call the predefined `mvn` function so outputting the string `mvn ...` to the console wouldn't be enough - if I understand what you did correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options. You can either call `function mvn` with an array of arguments instead of a string, or you can split the string.

So, either leave the function as is and use

```
mvn-failsafe-debug clean, install
```

Or change it to

```
function mvn {
    param(
        [parameter(Position=0)]
        [string] $arguments
    )

    Start-Process "$($env:M2_HOME)\bin\mvn.bat" -ArgumentList ($arguments -split " ")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Swoogan, your `$(arguments -split " ")` finally gave what I needed.

For comprehension the solution I use for now listed as follows (as a simple use case `mvn-eval` as a more complex one `mvn-surefire-debug`):

```
function mvn {
 param(
  [parameter(Position=0)]
  [string] $arguments
 )
 & "$($env:M2_HOME)\bin\mvn.bat" ($arguments -split " ")
}

function mvn-eval {
 param (
  [string] $Dexpression="basedir",
  [parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
  $args
 )
 mvn "help:evaluate $args"
}

function mvn-surefire-debug {
 param (
    [string] $Dmaven_surefire_debug="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_shmem,server=y,address=Maven,suspend=n"
  , [parameter(Position=0, ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
  $remains
 )
 mvn """`-Dmaven.surefire.debug=$Dmaven_surefire_debug"" $remains"
}
```